# The Internet checksum will *not* detect the error?

Tags: networking

Is it possible to flip *two* bits in a large message such that the Internet checksum will *not* detect the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as an Internet checksum.

Some of the protocols in the Internet protocol suite do however include a checksum. These are generally computed as a modulus-65535 sum, which means that every 16th bit position will contribute the same to the final value.

Thus if you flip one bit from 0 to 1 and another bit from 1 to 0, and if those two bits are a multiple of 16 bits away from each other in the packet, then the checksum will be unaffected. So it is easy to construct a scenario in which two bits can be flipped in a packet without the checksum detecting it.

For example imagine a packet containing these bytes 47 6f 6f 64 (hex). The second byte ends with a 1-bit and the fourth byte ends with a 0-bit. Those bits are 16 positions apart, so if we flip them both, the checksum will be unaffected. 47 6e 6f 65 has exactly two bits flipped, and it will have the same checksum.

It is however important to notice that these checksums do not cover everything sent over the Internet, so undetected corruption is more likely to happen for other reasons.

Now lets consider individual protocols.

**IPv4** has a header checksum. It only covers the header, so any corruption of the payload is not detected. Due to each router having to update the TTL field, the checksum has to be recomputed at each hop. It is easy to introduce an implementation bug in which corrupted data could result in this checksum being recomputed over the corrupted data.

**IPv6** does not have any header checksum. It was eliminated due to the problems mentioned above, and because there is a small performance benefit from not having to update it, and because checksums at other protocol layers are better suited.

**TCP** computes a checksum over all of the payload data and the IP addresses and protocol number as well. So even if the IP address is corrupted in-flight and the packet is delivered to the wrong destination because of that, then the TCP checksum can detect it and discard the packet.

**UDP** like TCP computes a checksum over payload data, IP addresses and protocol number. This however is optional. UDP packets can be sent over IPv4 with a zero in the checksum field in which case the recipient will accept the data regardless of any corruption of the payload data in transit. That is only true of IPv4 though. In IPv6 the UDP checksum is mandatory. This presumably is to compensate for the lack of header checksum, which means the UDP checksum is the only protection to ensure a packet is dropped in case an IP address was corrupted in transit.

**UDPlite** behaves exactly like UDP except that the checksum doesn't have to cover all of the payload data. The sender decides how many of the bytes (counting from the start of the packet) are required to be covered by checksum. Corruption at the end of the packet will remain undetected.